# Resolve IEnumerable of All Types that Implement Generic Interface in Autofac

Tags: c#, .net-core, autofac

I want to be able to resolve a collection of services from Autofac that represents all registered types which implement an open generic interface.

```
public interface IEntityService<in T> where T : Entity
{
    void DoEntityWork(T entity);
}
```

I have many classes that inherit `Entity` and many corresponding service classes which implement `IEntityService` for that Entity.

```
public class EntityA : Entity { }
public class EntityB : Entity { }
public class EntityC : Entity { }

public class EntityAService : IEntityService<EntityA>
{
    public void DoEntityWork(EntityA entity)
}

public class EntityBService : IEntityService<EntityB>
{
    public void DoEntityWork(EntityB entity)
}

public class EntityCService : IEntityService<EntityC>
{
    public void DoEntityWork(EntityB entity)
}
```

Here is how I am registering them with Autofac:

```
builder.RegisterType<EntityAService>().As<IEntityService<EntityA>();
builder.RegisterType<EntityBService>().As<IEntityService<EntityB>();
builder.RegisterType<EntityCService>().As<IEntityService<EntityC>();
```

What I would like to be able to do is to resolve each one of those `IEntityService` registrations in a collection.  However, attempting to inject them with the following code returns an empty collection:

```
public class MyProcessingClass(IEnumerable<IEntityService<Entity>> entityServices)
{
    _entityServices = entityServices;
}
```

I have tried instead registering them all `As<IEntityService<Entity>>()`, but this throws an `ArgumentException` with the following message:

```
The type 'MyProject.Services.EntityAService' is not assignable to service 'MyProject.Interfaces.IEntityService'1[[MyProject.Models.Entity]]
```

How can I resolve all of the types which implement `IEntityService` with a type argument that implements `Entity`?

Comment: Someone already mentioned contravariance, so I'll just chime in on the Autofac portion. I don't believe Autofac supports resolving all types of an open generic interface (IEntityService<>). You have to resolve a closed type of the interface (IEntityService<EntityC>. You can consider using a non-generic interface, if your use case allows. Then you can resolve a collection of all types implementing the non-generic interface.

Comment: @jandrew Guru Stron also mentioned using a non-generic interface.  I've been playing with that idea since the suggestion, but have yet to determine how I'll be able to implement that while maintaining my specific type usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autofac doesn't support this sort of thing out of the box. There is a [`ContravariantRegistrationSource`](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/ac840a25dd/src/Autofac/Features/Variance/ContravariantRegistrationSource.cs) but it does sort of the inverse of this - if you register `IEntityService<Entity>` and then resolve `IEntityService<EntityA>` it'll resolve the `IEntityService<Entity>` instance for you. It doesn't allow you to resolve `IEnumerable<IEntityService<Entity>>` and locate all the derived types.

Comment: Thanks for the response on this.  I tried a few other workarounds based on this and other responses, but none would allow me to resolve my closed types in the way that I wanted to.  I'll stick with resolving them all individually for now, until I can either figure out how to make my own RegistrationSource that accomplishes this or change up my designto not need it.

Answer (score 1):

This is how [contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) works in C# works, `EntityAService` is not `IEntityService<Entity>`, this relation works another way around:

```
public class EntityService : IEntityService<Entity>
{
    public void DoEntityWork(Entity entity) { }
}

IEntityService<EntityA> x = new EntityService();
```

One way around would be introducing a non-generic version of `IEntityService`, registering all your entity services as that one and resolving `IEnumerable<IEntityService>`.

Comment: I'm still relatively new to software development so please pardon my ignorance... my purpose for using `IEntityService<T> where T : Entity` is to force an implementer to specify the specific `Entity` type that the class will handle and then only be able to operate on that specific `Entity` type in the implementation.  A non-generic `IEntityService` would only allow me to restrict each member to `Entity` and not a more derived type.  Am I thinking about this incorrectly?  I'm sure there's a better way to do what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @draconastar yes, you thinking correctly. Idea is that service should implement both interfaces - generic for single interface use and non-generic for `IEnumerable<IEntityService<Entity>>` (`IEntityService<Entity>` in this context can be replaced with a non-generic version).

Comment: I really appreciate your input here!  I think I understand.  If I were to create a non-generic `IEntityService` interface then I could implement both and retrieve it as a collection.  My question here is, then wouldn't I be limited to calling non-generic interface methods since I retrieved them as the non-generic interface?  I would really need specific access to the generic interface members to process each Entity differently.

Comment: @draconastar What are you trying to achieve by resolving a collection of services? If you need to use a generic interface, it makes more sense to just resolve each closed type individually. i.e. `IEntityService<EntityA>` `IEntityService<EntityB>` etc).

Comment: @jandrew In practice, I have something like 30 `Entity` types.  For the time being I'm doing exactly as you said and resolving each individually, but the class they're being injected into has 30 fields, 30 constructor arguments, etc.  I'd like to be able to clean it up

Comment: @draconastar you can automate it with empty `IEntityService` thus introducing "convention" that generic one should implement also empty non-generic one for you to be able to resolve it in a collection..

Comment: @draconastar I would lean towards this being more of a design issue, based on what you've told us. I can't provide much of a recommendation without knowing more about your use case but I will suggest reading up on the SOLID principles and evaluating whether your interface design follows these principles. Specifically, the Single Responsibility Principle (S) and the Liskov Substitution Principle (L). Like I said, I can't say definitively whether your design violates these but I do suspect these two principles may help you find a better design for your interfaces and help you clean things up.

Comment: @GuruStron Resolving a collection of the non-generic `IEntityService` prevents me from being able to provide the generic type argument to other classes and processes that rely on them.  So your idea would work in one respect, where I'd be able to resolve my collection of service classes, but then no good way to generically reference the specific `Entity` types that they provide to `IEntityService<T>` as a type argument.

Comment: @jandrew I'm honestly not knowledgeable enough to argue with that; I'd suspect you're right.  I'm certain that my design is flawed, or at least that it could be improved.  That being said, the only real problem I'm trying to "solve" is needing to explicitly resolve each of the closed types, as you suggested above.  It's a bit cumbersome to do with so many in service and resolving them dynamically would leave me with one less place to update as support for additional Entities is added.  I will take your recommendation and read up on SOLID principles - thank you very much!